# Impossible to set an attribute to a string?

Tags: python

Usually, you can set an arbitrary attribute to a custom object, for instance

```
----------
>>> a=A()
>>> a.foo=42
>>> a.__dict__
{'foo': 42}
>>> 
----------
```

On the other hand, you can't do the same binding with a string object :

```
----------
>>> a=str("bar")
>>> a.foo=42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> a.__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>>
----------
```

Why ?

Answer (score 11):

Because the `str` type is a type wich does not has an attribute dict. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), "Classes" section:

> A class has a namespace implemented by a dictionary object.
>   Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this
>   dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]`

You can also enforce something similar on custom objects:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     __slots__=('a', )
... 
>>> a = X()
>>> a.a = 2
>>> a.foo = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

In general, you should not be setting nor modifying fields of objects that you are not supposed to. The documentation of the specific data type should reference you what fields are available for *public* modification.

For example, an `ReadOnlyPoint` object, where the x and y coordinates are set only on object construction:

```
>>> class ReadOnlyPoint(object):
...     __slots__ = ('_x', '_y')
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...             self._x = x
...             self._y = y
...     def getx(self):
...             return self._x
...     def gety(self):
...             return self._y
...     x = property(getx)
...     y = property(gety)
... 
>>> p = ReadOnlyPoint(2, 3)
>>> print p.x, p.y
2 3
>>> p.x = 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> p._x = 9
>>> print p.x, p.y
9 3
```

While the `x` and `y` properties are read-only, accessing the object internals allows you to alter the object's state.

The inhability to add a new field to an `str` object is an implementation detail, specific to the Python version that you are using.

Comment: Is not it a result of the fact that `str` type is basically designed as immutable? If you create a class (empty class, as in my example) inheriting from `str`, you will not get the mentioned error. For tuples however you will get this error (they are also immutable).

Comment: @Tadeck Well, both reasons come into play true - string is built in and doesn't have a `__dict__`, just like user-defined classes with `__slots__` modulo [edge cases](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots). It also wouldn't support attribute assignment anyway as strings are immutable. That can also be seen in the second error message by OP ("str object has no attribute __dict__").

Comment: @Tadeck It has _nothing_ to do with mutability. Try it with a `list`, you'll get the same result. You can't do it to any of the basic built-in types

Comment: Yes, `str` is immutable. However the OP asked specifically about the reasons on why the str object can't be modified, a data type wich don't contain an attribute dict. The error is raised because the Pythom VM can't find that dict. If you create a subclass of `str` you are in fact adding an attribute dict to your objects, making `MyStr` instances mutable.

Comment: @Tadeck thanks to you for asking. You forced me to do some little research.

Comment: @vz0: " _Forced_ " is such a strong word - I would prefer " _encouraged_ ". Lol. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @vz0 Thanks for your response but it doesn't exactly answer my question. How am I able to know in advance if a given object provides a __dict__ attribute ? What the official documentation says about it  ?

Comment: @agf Interesting answer, you are right, the same behaviour occurs with the list type. Does the documentation explain this ?

Comment: @candide None of the built-in types have `__dict__`s... all user defined classes do unless they have `__slots__` like vzo's example. If you want to understand the inner workings of Python, like this for example, the place to start is the [Data Model Reference Page](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: @agf In fact, some built-in type object have a __dict__, for instance any custom function has a dictionary attribute.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

> If the class has a **setattr**() or **delattr**() method, this is
>   called instead of updating the instance dictionary directly.

[http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**setattr**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Comment: I have checked **setattr** documentation before posting and this didn't help me.